# Top-coded survey data (Income)

Tags: regression, econometrics, multiple-imputation, censoring

Top-coded income data are often modeled with a Pareto distribution, but that is controversial.  What would be wrong with declaring those values as missing and then using multiple imputation (MI) to generate values for those cases using a normal model while assigning a lower bound as is allowed in [IVEware](http://www.isr.umich.edu/src/smp/ive/) (as long as the number of missing cases is small, say <5%)?

IVEware uses sequential regression multiple regression imputation.  From p.2 in the article below the algorithm is:

> The basic strategy creates imputations through a sequence of multiple regressions, varying the type of regression model by the type of variable being imputed. Covariates include all other variables observed or imputed for that individual. The imputations are defined as draws from the posterior predictive distribution specified by the regression model
>   with a flat or noninformative prior distribution for the parameters in the regression model. The sequence of imputing missing values can be continued in a cyclical
>   manner, each time overwriting previously drawn values, building interdependence among imputed values and exploiting the correlational structure among covariates. To
>   generate multiple imputations, the same procedure can be applied with different random starting seeds or taking every P th imputed set of values in the cycles mentioned above.

From p. 3 the conditional regressions are based on:

Each conditional regression is based on one of the
following models:

1. A normal linear regression model on a suitable scale
   (for example, a BoxCox power transformation may be used to achieve normality) if Y j is continuous;
2. A logistic regression model if Y j is binary;
3. A polytomous or generalized logit regression model
   if Y j categorical;
4. A Poisson loglinear model if Y j is a count variable;
   and
5. A twostage model where zeronon zero status is imputed using logistic regression, and conditional on nonzero status, a normal linear regression model is used to impute nonzero
   values, if Y j is mixed.

Comment: So how exactly does IVEware go about this? How is logistic model applicable here?

Comment: It uses sequential regression multiple imputation.  The details are here: http://www.statcan.gc.ca/ads-annonces/12-001-x/5857-eng.pdf.  From p. 2:

Comment: From this document, it appears that continuous variables would be predicted using a normal model. Thus once again I am asking, how is logistic model applicable here? Does IVEware support Pareto distribution at all?

Comment: Should have said normal rather than logistic in this case.  I applogize for the oversight.  IVEware picks the appropriate model based on the type of outcome, e.g., binary, continuous, counts, categorical.  So normal, logistic, Poisson.

Comment: I'll also add that my approach assumes that I can find suitable non-missing auxillary variables to use as predictors of income.  I think one reason Pareto is commonly used is that the upper income dstribution is non-linear, but none of my software offers anything outside of what I've listed above.  I wonder if normal regression would be good enough if the number of cases was limited.  I know that may be a stretch, but people here probably have a lot more experience with these matters than I.  Maybe a log transform would help?

Comment: Normal model is woefully wrong for the (levels of) top incomes, and even after the logs, I doubt it would produce sufficiently heavy tails. You would want to either do an even more aggressive Box-Cox transformation (say -0.25), or explicitly write the code to produce the Pareto distribution if your main analysis software allows that.